# pageslts error: very old endfloat in texlive 2013

Tags: floats, errors, texlive, lastpage, endfloat

The package pageslts in TeX Live 2013 complains about "very old endfloat package detected", but the recent endfloat version 2.5d is loaded. A minimum working example showing this error is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
asdf
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with pdflatex throws the error

```
! Package pageslts Error: Incompatible, very old endfloat package detected..
```

and warns about

```
Package pageslts Warning: Incompatible package lastpage detected:
```

Something in the logic of checking the packagedate in pageslts.sty seems to go wrong.

Comment: One of the braces in the tests is misplaced. Make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, fixed!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug that has been fixed in the post recent release of the package.

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fischer (thanks!) already pointed out in a comment:

> One of the braces in the tests is misplaced. Make a bug report.

(How to/where to report a bug: please see the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pageslts/README) of the package.)

The bug (sorry for that) has been fixed in ver­sion 1.2f of 2015-12-21, available at

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts.